# SwiftUI - How to achieve the equivalent of a switch/case within a VStack

Tags: swiftui, switch-statement, vstack

I have a set of 6 dials, but want to update them differently.

[image: 6 Dials]

They are generated in sequence from a loop that starts with:

```
ForEach(stats_Data){stat in
                    VStack(spacing: 14){
                        HStack{
                            Text(stat.title)
                                .dialTitleStyle()
                        } 
                        // Draw Circles
                        ZStack{
                            Circle()...
```

And the generic code that displays the arc is shown below:

```
Circle()
     .trim(from: (stats_Data[stat.id].startData / stat.goal), to: (stats_Data[stat.id].currentData / stat.goal))
     .stroke(stat.color, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round))
     .frame(width: (circleRadius) / 2, height: (circleRadius) / 2)
```

When I come to the dial values (arc bit) I want to handle each dial individually. Historically I would have used a switch/case approach:

```
 switch stat.id {
      case 0:
            UpdateDial1…
      case 1:
            UpdateDial2…
      case 2:
            UpdateDial3…
      case 3:
            UpdateDial4…
      case 4:
            UpdateDial5…
      default:
            UpdateDial6…
}
```

If I use this approach in SwiftUI the canvas preview times out (forever).

So, how do you generate the dials individually in SwitftUI?

Comment: You can do several things to improve this. First, you could factor out a "GaugeView" that takes a `stat`. Then you could have a computed property on your `stat` that would supply a `formattedString` (that would be the place for your switch) to your view and just render it. I guess my main point is that this code could benefit from better separation (presentation/logic).

Comment: Will investigate - many thanks.